# Export Data to the CSV file using Jsp and Javascript

Tags: javascript, jsp, csv, graph

In my project i have some code like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var fnames = ["aa","bb","cc","dd"];

var lnames = ["rr","bb","ff","kk"];
</script>
```

The abod code is there in one Jsp file, with the above data we are creating one line graph and now i want to export that chart data to the CSV file. I don't have any idea on this, can anybody help me in this regard.